# Ember.js + Sinatra + Sprockets, trying to use separate files for handlebars templates

Tags: ember.js, sinatra, sprockets, handlebars.js

I'm currently writing an Ember app with a small Sinatra back end. My previous Ember project used a Rails back end with the [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails) gem. I'm using a similar directory structure to the one that ember-rails generates. The app structure looks something like the following.

```
  /app
    /assets
      /stylesheets
      /javascripts
        /vendor
        /models
        /controllers
        /routes
        /views
        /templates
            --various templates with .hbs extension--
        applcation.js
        router.js
        store.js
    /models
    /views
      layout.erb
  app.rb
  config.ru
  Gemfile
```

I've had no issues setting up the app with sprockets. The ember app is loaded and rendered into the layout template below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      {{ outlet }}
    </script>

    <script src="assets/javascripts/application.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that none of my .hbs template files are detected and rendered into the outlet. If I move the templates into script tags in the layout then they render correctly.
I've tried using [handlebars_assets](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets), [sinatra-handlebars](https://github.com/benkitzelman/sinatra-handlebars), and [sinatra-ember](https://github.com/gamepoet/sinatra-ember) but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Sinatra::AssetPipeline](https://github.com/kalasjocke/sinatra-asset-pipeline) and [HandlebarsAssets](https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets) in a Sinatra wrapped ember.js app and it works fine with this configuration:

```rb
configure do
  register Sinatra::AssetPipeline
  set :assets_precompile, %w(application.js application.css libs.js templates.js)
  sprockets.append_path HandlebarsAssets.path
  HandlebarsAssets::Config.ember = true
end
```

You can see it in action at https://github.com/mynewsdesk/postman